# Java Firebase Database Setting

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
Record{
    Push_key(): 
    {
        duration: "30"
        rate: "2"
    }
}

Account{
    Push_key():
    {
        email:"abc@gmail.com"
        Rate:"2"
    }
}
```

Above shows the Firebase database structure.
I have a button where it save records into database while clicked:

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Record");
        String key = ref.push().getKey();
        ref.child(key).child("rate").setValue(strRate);
    }
});
```

where strRate is defined public and declared as below:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
String email = user.getEmail();
DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Account");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("email").startAt(email).endAt(email+"\uf8ff");
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            strRate = child.child("Rate").getValue().toString();
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

Question: **After** saving the record into the Record table in firebase, I change the value of Rate in Account with email: "abc" from "2" to "1". The change is only made in Account table but somehow the saved record in Record table changed with the modification made in Account table. The initial Rate: "2" in Record table changed to "1" when the changes is made in Account table where the Rate: "2" is changed into Rate: "1". After searching around, I suspect that this happens due to onDataChanged() for that strRate. Wish to get answer!

Comment: Can you please share the code for the whole page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to know why this is heppening. It's exactly what you guessed, you've attached a  value listener `addValueEventListener()` to the **Accounts** location and anytime something changes in that node you'll receive a callback to this listener.

If you want that to happen just once, you should use `singleValueEvent` listeners. If you want to have control over when you want to receive values or not and still want to use a `valueEventListener` you should hold to a reference of that listener and remove it from the reference whenever you don't want it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But instead of changing the `Listeners` I added the `removeEventListener` and it solves my problem! Thanks!